# how to check oracle db connectivity using shell script with sysdba as login id

Tags: linux, shell, logic

i want to check if the db is up by connecting to the db and if connected then exit and print that the db is up else bring up the db by loggin in the same way and do startup and exit.

I tried the below, im not tht fluent in script, pardon my mistakes

```
#!/bin/sh

 echo "exit" | $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -S -L  / as sysdba 
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]
 then
       echo "dp up"
  else
      echo "not up  starting $ORACLE_SID db"
      ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba << EOF
      startup
      exit;
       EOF
   done
```

The error is that it always print db is down even when db is up and the startup doesnt get executed, it prints no such path or couldnt connect as sysdba, i tried the change_on_install password but that also doesnt work. but manually i am able to login with path/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba and connect to db.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do (cannot test):

```
#!/bin/sh

if echo "SELECT 'TRUE'; exit" |
    $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -S -L  / as sysdba |
    grep -q 'TRUE'
then 
    echo "dp up"  
else                                      
    echo >&2 "not up  starting $ORACLE_SID db"     
    $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba <<-EOF
    startup
    exit
    EOF
fi
```

The idea behind, is that you don't need to test return value of last command, you can rely on the return code of `grep` in *quiet mode* transparently under the hood.

```
if true; then
    echo ok # will be outputted
fi

if false; then
    echo ok # will not be outputted 
fi
```

Comment: Have you tested, is this works?